# How to print a usage statement when no arguments are passed?

Tags: python, argparse

I am passing a single, positional argument string called FILE, but when no arguments are passed, I want it to print a usage statement.

Every time I write './files.py' in my command-line with no arguments after it, my code does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```
import argparse
import re

#--------------------------------------------------
def get_args():
    """get arguments"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Create Python script',
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument('FILE', help='Pass a file', type=str)

    return parser.parse_args()

#--------------------------------------------------

def main():
    """main"""
    args = get_args()
    FILE = args.FILE.IGNORECASE()

    if len(args) != 1:
        print("Usage: files.py {}".format(FILE))
        sys.exit(1)

# --------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected outcome:

```
$ ./files.py
Usage: files.py FILE
```

What I am getting:

```
$./files.py
$
```

Comment: I don't think the only issue was calling the `main()` method.

Comment: What happens if you do provide arguments?

Comment: Mod's should consider opening this question, so substantial answers can be posted, cheers!

Comment: Like OP stated, *I have main() added in my own code, I just forgot to add it in this question.* PS. I could post an answer that would very likely solve his problem! :D

Comment: I am still not getting a usage statement printed. I just get nothing returned when I run './files.py'. Also, I have called the main() function at the end of my code.

Comment: @DirtyBit As the question currently stands, adding ``main()`` *does* solve the problem. If there is a different problem, the question must be edited to make clear which problem it is.

Comment: @kevin Edit your question, add the missing part with the output you're getting and desired.

Comment: @kevin Should'nt the output you're getting be: `usage: test.py [-h] FILE
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: FILE`?

Comment: @keving Do you have a shebang at the start of your script? If not, do you get any non-python error message, say ``import: missing an image filename `import' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/1302.``?

Comment: Yes I have included '#!/usr/bin/env python3' at the top of my script and my code doesn't return any errors. I am just confused why it is not returning the usage statement. @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Do you get *any* output from the script in any situation? Do ``print`` statements outside of functions work? What happens if you do provide arguments?

Comment: After the edit, the problem appears not to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You never run `main`...

```
import argparse
import re
#--------------------------------------------------
def get_args():
    """get arguments"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Create Python script',
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('FILE', help='Pass a file', type=str)
return parser.parse_args()
#--------------------------------------------------
def main():
    """main"""
    args = get_args()
    FILE = args.FILE.IGNORECASE()
    if len(args) != 1:
        print("Usage: files.py {}".format(FILE))
        sys.exit(1)
main()
```

Comment: I have main() added in my own code, I just forgot to add it in this question, but I still encounter the same problem I stated above.

Comment: My output...` ~ python3 test.py` `usage: test.py [-h] FILE` `test.py: error: the following arguments are required: FILE`

Comment: @kevin That behaviour is not reproducible with the code you have shown. Please provide a complete and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the entry point of your code. If you want to call this as you are describing (`./files.py`) you need to define the main entry point like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    """main"""
    args = get_args()
    FILE = args.FILE.IGNORECASE()

    if len(args) != 1:
        print("Usage: files.py {}".format(FILE))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell your operating system that the script must be executed by Python. Add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
...
```

Otherwise, you have to explicitly execute the script with Python:

```
python3 ./files.py
```

---

You must *call* your `main` function. A good place is at the end of the script, guarded to be run on execution only:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  # do not run on import
    main()
```

This gives the desired output:

```
$ python3 so_script.py
usage: so_script.py [-h] FILE
so_script.py: error: the following arguments are required: FILE
```

Note that `argparse` already creates the usage and help messages for you. There is no need to create them yourself. In fact, `argparse` will end your script before your own usage information is run.

If you do not want to have the `-h` switch, pass [`add_help=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#add-help) when creating the argument parser.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Create Python script',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    add_help=False,
)
```

Comment: I have the main() function called, but I still get nothing. Also, I don't want it to return [-h] if that's possible.

Comment: @kevin With the code you have postet, missing ``main`` is the only problem. We cannot guess what *additional* parts you have not shown to produce another problem. Please edit your question to include the minimal code required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @kevin You might be missing a shebang, but in that case you should still get errors from the Shell trying to make sense of your Python code.